# Study of Matrix Calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I need to study matrix calculus such as integration, differentiation, differentiation  of functions of determinants and inverse matrices and then also other matrix based calculations such as decomposition techniques.

And I need to know these operations for matrices defined in the complex domain rather than real valued.

Could someone please recommend me a book or a comprehensive online resource ?

Thank you

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this question, which isn't answered yet, but don't want to duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the following links:

- [Matrix Reference Manual](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/intro.html#Intro)

  - [Matrix Reference Manual: References](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix)
- [The Matrix Cookbook (PDF)](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)